# gRPC Java server with setReuseAddress(true)?

Tags: netty, grpc-java, so-reuseport

I am working on a gRPC server written in Java. It uses `NettyServerBuilder` to start/run the server. I am wondering, how to set `setReuseAddress(true)` for the server, so that it can restart quickly (either on crashes or maintenance restarts.)

This is the current startup:

```java
import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder;

//...

private Server server;

//...

server = NettyServerBuilder
                .forPort(port)
                .permitKeepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
                .permitKeepAliveTime(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addService(this.queryService)
                .addService(this.commandService)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```java
Server server = NettyServerBuilder
            .forPort(port)
            // ...
            .withChildOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
            .build();
```

Comment: you may also want to use `withOption(...)` as well.

Comment: @NormanMaurer you may be confusing `io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder` with some other class, but this one does not have `withOption(...)` method.